# KOTLIN: every time adding new item to recyclerview, the timer created again and and the old one still running in background

Tags: android-recyclerview, timer

class FutureAppleAdapter(futureAppleList: ArrayList, private val activity: Activity) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<FutureAppleAdapter.FutureAppleHolder>() {

```
private var futureAppleList: ArrayList<Apple>

init {
    this.futureAppleList = futureAppleList
}

private lateinit var mListener: OnAppleStateClickListener
private lateinit var timerListener: OnItemTimerFinished

interface OnAppleStateClickListener {
    fun onAppleStateClick(apple: Apple)
}

interface OnItemTimerFinished {
    fun onItemTimerFinished(position: Int, apple: Apple)
}

fun setOnItemTimerFinish(listener: OnItemTimerFinished) {
    timerListener = listener
}

fun setOnAppleStateClick(listener: OnAppleStateClickListener) {
    mListener = listener
}

inner class FutureAppleHolder(itemView: View, listener: OnAppleStateClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_apple_title)
    val time: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_apple_time)
    val appleState: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_apple_state)

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onAppleStateClick(futureAppleList[adapterPosition])
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FutureAppleHolder {
    val view =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.apple_cell_view, parent, false)
    return FutureAppleHolder(view, mListener)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return futureAppleList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FutureAppleHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentApple = futureAppleList[position]

    holder.title.text = currentApple.title


    val currentDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val endDate = currentApple.endDate
    val timeRemaining = endDate - currentDate

    val newTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timeRemaining, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            holder.time.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()
            Log.i("checkData","time remaining: ${currentApple.title} => ${millisUntilFinished / 1000}")
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
                Log.i("checkDataFinished", "item finished: ${currentApple.title}")
                Log.i("checkDataFinished", "item position: ${holder.bindingAdapterPosition}")
                futureAppleList.removeAt(holder.bindingAdapterPosition)
                db.deleteAppleByTitle(currentApple.title)
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.bindingAdapterPosition)
                notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.bindingAdapterPosition, futureAppleList.size + 1)
                timerListener.onItemTimerFinished(position, currentApple)
            }
        }
    newTimer.start()
}
```

}

i tried more than solution:

1. timer in different class.
2. create on instance of timer object.
3. use map to save old timers, and every time cancel them.

every time i got the same results without any progress